# How to implement a function like stackoverflow's `add a comment` in Rails' app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a mini SO with Rails, and find SO's `add a comment` under every question and answer very interesting and difficult for me:

after you click `add a comment` link, `add a comment` link will hide and a form with `textarea` and `submit` will show.

At the beginning, for a question with activity No 47, I implement this using the snippet code like this:

```
<div id="comments" class="comments">
     <button type="button" id="comment-btn-47">add a comment</button>
     <div id="new-comment-47" style="display:none">
        ...
     </div>
</div>
```

and when clicking `add a comment` using code:

```
<% content_for :javascript  do%>
$("#comment-btn-47").click(function(){
   $("#new-comment-47").show(0, function(){
      $("#comment-btn-47").hide() });   
<% end %>

NOTE:here `47` is the answer activity No
```

after writing the content for a comment and clicking the button called `submit`, the last part of saving and showing the comments include the following code:

```
  $("#new-comment-47").hide();
  $("#comment-btn-47").show();
```

It works fine when a question does not answer, but when a question has one or more than one answers, the above resolution fails. After thinking simply about it, I find that `<% content_for :javascript do %> ... <% end %>` needs a more complicated resolution, for example, if there is a  question with No 47 and a corresponding answer with No 74, so in `<% content_for :javascript do %> ... <% end %>`, I need:

```
<% content_for :javascript  do%>
$("#comment-btn-47").click(function(){
   $("#new-comment-47").show(0, function(){
      $("#comment-btn-47").hide() });   

$("#comment-btn-74").click(function(){
   $("#new-comment-74").show(0, function(){
      $("#comment-btn-74").hide() });
<% end %>
```

Obviously, this not a idea resolution, what should I do? what things about `javascript`, `rails` or `css` I missed? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your difficulties are due to the fact that you are abusing element ID's. ID's are great for truly unique elements, but just usings ID's makes it extremely difficult to make good reusable code or moving your javascript out of your views where it has no place being in the first place.

```js
$('.answer, .question').on('click', '.add-a-comment', function(){
  var $button = $(this);
  $button.hide(); // hide the button
  // go up to the parent question
  // and the look down to find form.
  $button.parents('.answer, .question') 
    .find('.comment-form').removeClass('hidden');
});

// Silly example of adding an event handler and traversing 
$('.answer, .question').on('submit', '.comment-form', function(){
  var $form = $(this); 
  var $comments = $form.parents('.answer, .question') 
    .find('.comments');
  $comments.append('<li>' + $form.find('textarea').val() + '</li>'); 
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <!-- ... -->
  <section class="comments-box">
     <p>Blablabla...?</p>
     <ul class="comments">
        <li class="comment">Say what?</li>
        <!-- ... -->
     </ul> 
     <p>
       <button type="button" class="add-a-comment">add a comment</button>
     </p>
     <form class="comment-form hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="comment[question_id]" value="3">
        <textarea name="comment[body]"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="submit comment">
      </form>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="answer">
  <!-- ... -->
  <section class="comments-box">
     <p>Just add water</p>
     <ul class="comments">
        <li class="comment">This is silly.</li>
        <!-- ... -->
     </ul> 
     <p><button type="button" class="add-a-comment">add a comment</button></p>
     <form class="comment-form hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="comment[answer_id]" value="5">
        <textarea name="comment[body]"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="submit comment">
      </form>
  </section>
</div>
```